# Tags for non-fungible tokens

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I propose that tag [nft](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nft) be made a synonym for [non-fungible-tokens](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fungible-tokens).

Comment: Sounds sensible, can you turn this into more of a Q&A with the Q being "shall we" and the A being "yes", so that anyone who disagrees can post a competing answer?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Don't the number of upvotes and number of downvotes on the question itself contain enough information on how desirable readers find it? After all, in my question, I ask nothing, I merely propose.

Comment: OK, I guess it's not worth a lot of bureaucracy here and looking back I also haven't been consistent about the approach :-)

Comment: I would propose that NFT and NFT related questions simply be off-topic... I can’t imagine a, non-technical, personal finance angle specific to NFTs that would be unique to NFTs.  “Should I buy?” Is opinion and off topic. Tax consequences of donating art to a museum isn’t NFT specific, Taxes/capital gains applies broadly to buying and selling of assets etc these people should probably be directed to the crypto board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this synonym as it seems fairly uncontroversial and I can always undo it if there is pushback.